# Extracting pixels of raster1 that overlap with raster2 in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pixel, extract

I have 2 partly overlapping raster datasets, would like to extract pixels of one dataset that overlap with another dataset.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS for Desktop to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a long search I could find the solution. [Extract by Mask](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) tool in spatial analyst toolbox can be the best solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional statements either through the Con() tool or through Raster Calculator. Con(Raster1, Raster2) would translate to "if there is a non-null cell in Raster1 at a location, output the cell value of Raster2.

Answer (score 0):

The intersect tool in ArcMap may be what you're looking for: http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000000p000000

```
-Intersect will combine the overlapping section of both datasets
```

and if that isn't exactly what you're looking for, clip might do the job: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Clip_(Analysis)

```
-Clip will create a new feature of the target layer based on overlap with the source layer.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I think these functions work for vector dataset, I am searching the similar tool which works for raster dataset.

Comment: I could've sworn these worked with raster data...I know I've used them on DEM's before.

Comment: Edit1: I may have linked the analysis toolset, but have you tried the coverage version of those tools?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed your comment. I couldn't use Clip, it requires vector data only. And also I could not use coverage tool, because it is not functioning in my software for unknown reason. Thanks for your suggestion.